# How AI can help learn mathematics

Tags: education-research

I am working with AI methods and thinking about how my daughter (also other kids) can learn mathematics with AI help easier (like showing where in learning path was biggest mistake and etc.)? I know it's a broad question, but any thoughts will be welcome.

Comment: Try doing a Google search and reading a few articles and then coming up with a more precise question or at least a more detailed lists of issues and ideas.  This is too broad and vague for anyone to spend time on as is.  You need to do more work first.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: I expanded my comment to an answer below.

Comment: The reverse, where [AI's are learning math from us](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/are-the-machines-upon-us) (e.g. see [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:gashqm9iip8J:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809043/)), already seems to be occurring! :)

Answer (score 4):

Audrey Watters does some good writing on the (long) history of education technology, which I would recommend you read. At a minimum, I think it would be useful to be aware of the history. For example, this spring, [Teaching Machines, or How the Automation of Education Became 'Personalized Learning'](http://hackeducation.com/2018/04/26/cuny-gc):

> “Personalized learning,” depending on how you define it, dates back to
>   Rousseau. Or it dates back further still – to Alexander the Great’s
>   tutor, some guy named Aristotle. It dates to the nineteenth century.
>   Or to the twentieth century. It dates to the rise of progressive
>   education theorists and practitioners. To John Dewey. Or to Maria
>   Montessori (often the only woman ever mentioned in any of these
>   tales). Or it dates to the rise of educational psychology. To B. F.
>   Skinner. To Benjamin Bloom. It dates to special education-related
>   legislation passed in the 1970s or to the laws passed the 1990s. Or it
>   dates to computer scientist Alan Kay’s 1972 essay “A Personal Computer
>   for Children of All Ages.” Or it dates to the Gates Foundation’s
>   funding grants and political advocacy in the early 2000s. Take your
>   pick.

Also, not mentioned above, you should be aware of [PLATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLATO_%28computer_system%29) (computer-assisted instruction system from U. Illinois, 1960-2006).